# Why MacOS clang can't use C++17 std?

Tags: c++, clang

I want to use c++1z in MacOS10.14.4, like this `g++ -std=c++1z test.cpp -o test`. But the clang can't compile the code.

The error as follows.

```
In file included from test.cpp:3:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/any:599:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_constructible<basic_string<char> &&, _RawValueType
      &>::value' "ValueType is required to be an lvalue reference or a CopyConstructible type"
    static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType, _RawValueType &>::value,
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:29:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::any_cast<std::__1::basic_string<char> &&>' requested here
    auto b = std::any_cast<std::string&&>(a); //< rvalue reference (no need for std::move)
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

But the same code can work on Linux. The code as follows.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

int main()
{
    // simple example 

    auto a = std::any(12);

    std::cout << std::any_cast<int>(a) << '\n'; 

    try {
        std::cout << std::any_cast<std::string>(a) << '\n';
    }
    catch(const std::bad_any_cast& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    // advanced example

    a = std::string("hello");

    auto& ra = std::any_cast<std::string&>(a); //< reference
    ra[1] = 'o';

    std::cout << "a: " << std::any_cast<const std::string&>(a) << '\n'; //< const reference

    auto b = std::any_cast<std::string&&>(a); //< rvalue reference (no need for std::move)

    // Note, 'b' is a move-constructed std::string, 'a' is now empty

    std::cout << "a: " << *std::any_cast<std::string>(&a) //< pointer
        << "b: " << b << '\n';
}
```

clang version: Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)

And I use the gcc to compile this code, but didn't work either.

Comment: Fails to compile for me live: https://godbolt.org/z/3a3BJt

Comment: You say "no need for std::move" but [the cppreference page has it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast). Why do you think there's no need for it? Have you tried with it?

Comment: Please be more specific about the Linux environment in which this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be from https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/200281/stdany-cast-static-assert-error-because-of-is-cons.html, which has an answer from Microsoft. The answer there was that this was a defect [LWG 2768](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2769), so the fix may not have been implemented in older implementations of the standard library. [For example](https://godbolt.org/z/nsDor9), this compiles in clang 6.0.0 and gcc 7.4, but not clang 7.0.0 and gcc 8.1.

The reason is that you can't take an rvalue reference of an lvalue any. Fix this by either taking an lvalue reference and moving that or taking an rvalue reference of a moved any:

```
std::move(std::any_cast<std::string&>(a));
std::any_cast<std::string&&>(std::move(a));
```